# Goethe - Prometheus - wie soll man eine Zeile verstehen?

Tags: vocabulary, poetry

In Goethes "Prometheus" ist es geschrieben.

> Und übe, Knaben gleich,
>   Der Disteln köpft,
>   An Eichen dich und Bergeshöh'n!

Die Distel ist eine Pflanze (thistles) und köpfen bedeutet doch jemanden den Kopf zu abschlagen. Deshalb machen diese Zeilen keinen Sinn für mich.

Wie soll man diese Zeilen verstehen?

Comment: Have you *seen* the plant? [It has a flower head.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disteln#/media/File:Milk_thistle_flowerhead.jpg) And so you can decapitate it. Very straightforward. Decapitation is not limited to human beings.

Comment: This is complicated by the weird (poetic) word order and the omission of a crucial article. Here is an untangled version: "Und übe dich an Eichen und Bergeshöhen, gleich einem Knaben, der Disteln köpft." Tricky expressions: *sich üben = practise, gleich einem = similar to a*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Bedecke deinen Himmel, Zeus,
>   Mit Wolkendunst!
>   Und übe, Knaben gleich,
>   Der Disteln köpft,
>   An Eichen dich und Bergeshöh’n!

The first line of the poem is addressing Zeus and tells him to cover the sky with clouds, effectively hiding the peak of mountains and treetops of oaks (“decapitating” them), which is compared to a small boy “decapitating” thistles.

It’s like:

> dear Zeus, just like a small boy dacapitates thistles you should decapitate tree and mountains with your clouds.

Comment: And why is the plural imperative used here?

Comment: "übe" is singular. Plural would be "übt" (or sometimes, more ancient, "übet")

Comment: Yes, but "köpft" is 2.Pl.

Comment: "köpft" is not an imperative here. It's 3rd Sg. Present and refers to "Knabe". What's a bit irritating is that the indefinite article "einem" before "Knaben" is omitted, which makes it look like a plural. You can only tell from the following "der" that it must be singular.

Comment: @Uwe That irritating bit is just a typo. It is "..., *dem* Knaben gleich, ...", according to [this source](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Goethes_Schriften_8_1789_207.jpg)

Comment: @Matthias One can find several versions of this poem, one with odd grammar (without article) and one with odd meter (with article). It may be a typo, but then it's a very old typo.

Comment: @Uwe Indeed - looks like it isn't a simple typo at all. I opened a question on this point: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23182/warum-noch-heute-und-%C3%BCbe-knaben-gleich-ohne-dem-in-goethes-prometheus

Comment: Nicht relevant für die Frage, aber mir erscheint das vorübergehende Verhüllen von Berg- und Baumspitzen durch Nebel doch etwas zu mild. Meine Vorstellung ist, daß Zeus sie eher mit Blitzen bearbeitet und dadurch die Spitze absprengt.