# Verschiedene, noch heute gebräuchliche Versionen von Goethes "Prometheus"

Tags: literature

Durch [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23043/goethe-prometheus-wie-soll-man-eine-zeile-verstehen) bin ich darauf aufmerksam geworden, dass offenbar noch heute eine Fassung von Goethes "Prometheus" in Gebrauch ist, in der der 3. Vers lautet:

> Und übe, Knaben gleich,

Ich kannte bislang nur

> Und übe, *dem* Knaben gleich,

und vermutete deshalb zunächst einen simplen Abschreibfehler - bestätigt durch Wikisource, demzufolge sowohl [Goethes eigene Erstveröffentlichung von 1789](http://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Prometheus_%28Gedicht,_fr%C3%BChe_Fassung%29) des Gedichts als auch seine [Ausgabe letzter Hand](http://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Prometheus_%28Gedicht,_sp%C3%A4te_Fassung%29) die Variante mit "dem" benutzen.

Mit etwas Nachforschen fand ich aber heraus ([Quelle](https://books.google.de/books?id=saIEO7E366gC&pg=PA174&dq=%22%C3%BCbe%20knaben%20gleich%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=dmVOVfmtB4uYsgHC84HwCA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%BCbe%20knaben%20gleich%22&f=false)), dass Goethe offenbar selbst ursprünglich die Variante ohne "dem" verwendet hatte und das Gedicht so auch erstmalig gedruckt wurde (1785, anonym, in Jacobis "Über die Lehre des Spinozas").

Es wäre also sicher zu einfach, die Variante ohne "dem" als Fehler abzutun - aber ich sehe auch keinen Grund, sie außerhalb literaturhistorischer Fachzirkel zu verwenden. Trotzdem passiert das, u.a. beim [Projekt Gutenberg](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/johann-wolfgang-goethe-gedichte-3670/118) und in diesem [aktuellen Lehrbuch](https://books.google.de/books?id=Od8tBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT86&dq=%22%C3%BCbe%20knaben%20gleich%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=dmVOVfmtB4uYsgHC84HwCA&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%BCbe%20knaben%20gleich%22&f=false), um nur zwei Beispiele anzuführen.

**Mein Frage nun**: warum ist die ältere Version, trotz der anders lautenden und von Goethe selbst verantworteten Veröffentlichungen, heute noch in Gebrauch? Habe ich vielleicht ein Puzzle-Stück in der Geschichte dieses Werks übersehen?

Comment: Ich halte "Knaben gleich" für einen Dativ Plural im Sinne von " wie es Knaben im allgemeinen tun".

Comment: @rogermue Das kann nicht sein, es heißt nämlich danach "*der* Disteln *köpft*".

Comment: Ja, du hast recht, hatte den Text nicht mehr so im Kopf.

Answer (score 2):

Es sieht ja wohl so aus, daß beide Fassungen direkt auf Goethe
zurückgehen, der anscheinend während seines Lebens mal der einen,
mal der anderen den Vorzug gegeben hat. Damit stellt sich die Frage,
was man mit der Veröffentlichung (oder, bei dramatischen oder
musikalischen Werken, der Aufführung) eines Werkes bezweckt.
Will man den letzten Willen eines Künstlers dokumentieren, oder
will man ein Kunstwerk *an sich* veröffentlichen/aufführen?

Es ist offensichtlich, daß man sich bei Wikisource auf irgendein
objektivierbares Kriterium zurückziehen muß – eine Auswahl nach
künstlerischem Geschmack funktioniert nur dann, wenn irgendjemand
die künstlerische Leitung innehat. Wenn aber ein solcher Zwang nicht
besteht (und die gesetzlichen Schutzrechte der Erben abgelaufen
sind), dann hat derjenige, der ein Werk veröffentlicht oder aufführt,
grundsätzlich die Freiheit, sich für diejenige Fassung zu entscheiden,
die er persönlich am überzeugendsten findet. Das kann, aber muß
nicht die letzte autorisierte Fassung sein. Manchmal setzt sich dann
auf dem Markt eine Version durch, manchmal (z.B. im Fall einiger
Bruckner-Sinfonien) eben nicht. Beim *Prometheus* ist ja klar, daß
beide Versionen ein kleines Problem haben (einmal ein merkwürdiges
Versmaß, einmal eine merkwürdige Grammatik) – ich persönlich kann
denjenigen, der dem glatteren Versmaß den Vorzug gibt, durchaus
verstehen.

Sicher kann man den Standpunkt vertreten, daß der letzte Wille
eines Künstlers hier der alleinige Maßstab sein sollte.
Aber was macht man dann mit Franz Kafka (bei dem der größere Teil
des Werkes nur deshalb erhalten geblieben ist, weil sein Freund
Max Brod die testamentarische Aufforderung, alles zu vernichten,
schlicht ignoriert hat)? Gar nicht veröffentlichen?

Comment: "Mal der einen, mal der anderen" klingt mMn wankelmütiger, als es die mir bekannte Quellenlage hergibt - ab der ersten von ihm selbst veranlassten Veröffentlichung scheint Goethe bei der "dem"-Fassung geblieben zu sein. Vorher zirkulierten verschiedene handschriftliche (Vorab-?)Fassungen, von denen eine, wohl ohne sein Zutun, veröffentlicht wurde. --- Das Argument mit dem Versmaß überzeugt mich auch nicht, immerhin geht es hier um eines der Paradebeispiele für freie Rhythmen. Abgesehen davon: was ist an "-^-^--" glatter als an "-^--^--"? (Du wirst ja wohl nicht "gleich" betonen wollen?)

Comment: Doch, ich würde die erste Strophe, im Gegensatz zu den folgenden,
tatsächlich als Folge von Jamben auffassen.
Für mich liegt auf "gleich", ebenso wie auf "pflückt"
oder "-höhn" zumindest eine Nebenbetonung.